# Skips the first repeated Value and fetch the 2nd Value - PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

PHP and MYSQLi

I am trying to get the below output: for a Project ID (PJ006)
I put the "date" column in Descending order first and then i want to skip all the Repeated value of the first value (Skip all entries of EM207) and display the immedate 2nd value (Output expected: EM206). This output is needed against the for a Project ID (PJ006)

```
Database:
     SL No.     Badge ID           Date               ProjectID    
        1        EM207     2015-05-12 00:00:00          PJ006
        2        EM207     2015-05-11 00:00:00          PJ006
        3        EM207     2015-05-09 00:00:00          PJ006       
        4        EM207     2015-05-09 00:00:00          PJ001   
        5        EM206     2015-05-08 00:00:00          PJ001   
        6        EM206     2015-09-05 00:00:00          PJ006   
        7        EM206     2015-09-03 00:00:00          PJ006   
        8        EM205     2015-09-01 00:00:00          PJ006
```

Expected output: For Project ID: PJ006,

```
Badge ID: EM206
```

PHP Code for: Using the First Badge ID (EM207), fetch the data of the Project ID PJ006 and display

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('serverIP','username','password','databasename');
 //This data i passed by Ajax
$someID = trim($_POST["storedValue"]);
//This query puts the date column in Desending Order
$query2 ="SELECT * FROM scores1 WHERE  ProjectID='$someID' order by  ScoreDate desc limit 1"; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query2)or die(mysqli_error());
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //the output is displayed here
    echo $row[1];
}
```

What modification is required in the above code **"to skip all the Repeated value of the first value (Skip all entries of EM207) and display the immediate 2nd value (Output expected: EM206)"**. This output is needed against the for a Project ID (PJ006)

Comment: you can use NOT IN operator in mysql

Comment: Can you suggest something in PHP, as this value keeps changing everyday. I need to pick the 2nd value skipping the first one (and all its entries that repeats when they are in descending)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT badgeId FROM tbl;`

Comment: What's the logical rule you're looking for when you're asking to skip ALL the `EM207` rows? Is it a certain value you want to skip? If so, you can just use `WHERE badgeid <> 'EM207'`

Comment: Since the Badge ID keeps changing, i cannot use value in my code.. so the logic is, I am more focused about the Project id PJ006, When i do descending, i need to skip all the rows of the First entry.. so i skip row 1 to row 4 and then output the value of EM206 from 6th row against the project ID PJ006

Comment: Is the `date` column useful for ordering?

Comment: @NevStokes Yes, the date column is required for ordering.. post the ordering is done. it has to remove duplicates in Badge ID, and then pick the 2nd district value from the top.. so in my case it will be EM206

Comment: Okay, but which EM206 — SL 6 or 7, or is it not really important?

Comment: @NevStokes i would be expeting the SL 6, because the date 2015-09-05 00:00:00, is the immediate next date for unique Badge ID for Project ID PJ006

Comment: Sorry, guess I'm slightly confused! Your data doesn't seem to be ordered by date descending. Are you actually after the *most recent* badge id for a given project id?

Comment: Let me put the question in the simple terms, from the database i have mentioned, which is the 2nd Badge ID for the Project ID "PJ006" from descending dates ? answer is: EM206 of the date 2015-09-05

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80680/discussion-between-nev-stokes-and-john-franky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     $query2 ="SELECT * FROM scores1 WHERE  ProjectID='$someID' order by ScoreDate desc limit 1"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query2)or die(mysqli_error());
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $badgeid=0; $proid=0;
    while($row= $database->fetch_array($result))
    {       
        if($badgeid!=$row['batchid'] || $proid!=$row['proid']; ){
        echo "$badgeid and $proid "
        $b=$row['batchid'];
        $p=$row['proid'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can use this, but even in that case after i use Distinct, the PHP code shoud pick the 2nd value ... what should be my php code

Comment: I think this code will get u rows which are not repeated so of course you can get  EM206 after EM207

Comment: That is the same thing i already have in my code.. can you suggest how to pick 2nd unique Badge ID against project ID PJ006 in PHP

Comment: Thamaraiselvam, In your code, can you point the exact value that picks the 2nd value ??

Comment: Trying it.. looks positive.. will update you asap.. working on the same

Comment: Cool do small changes if it is now working and let me know what result you are getting now?

Comment: Strange i am getting an unexpected error "," on this line if($badgeid!=$row['batchid'] || $proid!=$row['proid']; ){

Comment: Try this i have modified while loop and change `batchid` and `proid` according to your column name

Comment: Thamaraiselvam, the code does not skips the repeated value ? the output is still getting me the EM207 (but i need EM206).. .

Comment: then make `||` into `&&` in if condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80678/discussion-between-john-franky-and-thamaraiselvam).

Comment: That does not return any value :-(

Comment: come to chat dont post here

Comment: Thamaraiselvam: i have a question.. can you invite me to chat ?

Answer (score 2):

In this answer i am thanking Mr.Thamaraiselvam for helping me with the exact required output. Thanks You.

The Solution which worked:

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('serverIP','username','password','databasename');

  $query2 ="SELECT * FROM scores1 where ProjectID='12345' ORDER BY ScoreDate DESC"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query2)or die(mysqli_error());
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $badgeid=0; $proid=0 ; $date=0;
                $flag=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {       
       if($badgeid!=$row['BadgeID'] || $proid!=$row['ProjectID'] ){

                   if($flag==2){
                        echo "$badgeid and $date<br>";
                                                }
                                $flag++;


        $badgeid =$row['BadgeID'];
       $proid =$row['ProjectID'];
                   $date =$row['ScoreDate'];

        }

                }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thamaraiselvam, can i trouble you for 10min ? My next step to to get the 3rd Badge ID for the Project ID PJ006 , So i would like to Print EM205  2015-09-01. To archive this, i changed the if($flag==2) in the solution to if($flag==4), but noting shows up.. as you understand this time.. my next step is to get the Badge ID EM205 as my output. What would be the small modification in the solution shared by you ?

Comment: try to print echo $flag; and check, in which time it gets EM205 and give that value to flag

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as discussed, what you're actually after is the most recent badge id for a particular project - the fact that this is the second entry is a bit of a red herring and may not hold true in other scenarios.

I'd use a subquery to find the most recent entries for each project:

```
select
    badgeId,
    projectId
from
    scores1,
    (
        select
            max(date) as max,
            projectId
        from
            scores1
        group by
            projectId
    ) as sub
where
    scores1.date = sub.max
    and scores1.projectId = sub.projectId
```

You can then add a check for whichever project id you're interested in. Don't forget to add some indexes for better performance.